# Is there any way to get availableOutputs like availableInputs in AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, xcode, avaudiosession

I need to list available outputs (like BleutoothLE, HeadPhones, BuiltInReceiver) but i can just access currentRoute's output.

Can anyone access all available outputs, please share your comments ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options as far as I know:

- Add a `MPVolumeView` to your view and, set `showsVolumeSlider` to 0 and set `showsRouteButton` to 1.  This will put a system provided icon where the user can pick from available outputs.
- AVAudioSession has a very limited `overrideOutputAudioPort` method that can route audio to the built in speaker.

  ```
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:nil];
  ```

Comment: Thanks Dave for your interest but I have already looked at MPVolumeView .it gives only a button to show available output on UI but i need to access the list of available outputs in code and change audio route using them.

Comment: I believe there is no such access.  You can only retrieve a port description for the output of the current route via '[[[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute] outputs] firstObject]', not all available routes.  The outputs array always has one object.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why there wasn't a simple `availableOutputs` property.

But you can get a list of all available outputs by using the multi-route audio category and inspecting your current route's outputs:

```
let sesh = AVAudioSession()
try! sesh.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute)
try! sesh.setActive(true)

print("available outputs: \(sesh.currentRoute.outputs)\n")
```

Outputs (and inputs) come and go, causing route changes, so subscribe to the route change notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "routeChanged:",
    name: AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification,
    object:nil
)
```

**NB**: multi-route category has a lot of rules about when inputs/outputs that are intuitively available, are *actually* available (e.g. speaker isn't "available" when you have a USB soundcard plugged in, but wired headphones will be).

What are you trying to do? I've used multi-route to playback 4 channel audio, but I'm not sure if you actually can mix and match between the outputs.

Answer (score -4):

Get list of all the outputs using [AVAudioSession's currentRoute](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSessionRouteDescription_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/AVAudioSessionRouteDescription):

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSLog(@"Outputs: %@", [[session currentRoute] outputs]);
```

Comment: this only returns the current output route, not all available ones.